# Why does Java has a replaceAll(regex, replacement) but replaceAll(regex, regex)?

Tags: java, regex, replace, deprecated

**Java does have this function and Thank you for answering, it's too pity to lose attention on the API for me...**

For example:

```
String strOriginal = "A:B&C@D";
```

I think there should be a really nice method in java to change it like this:

```
String strNew = NewReplaceAll("(.*?)\\:(.*?)&(.*?)@(.*?)","\4_\3^\2(\1\2\2\1)");
```

This can give result like this:

```
AssertTrue(strNew.equalsWith("D_C^B(ABBA)") );
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation of replaceAll? It does exactly what you say.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation of `replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))? It **does** what you want it to do (except you need to double-escape the backslashes in the replacement). The replacement is not called "a regex" because it is not! You can't use any regex constructs there *except* placeholders!

Comment: Thanks everyone, I feel so speachless...

Answer (score 3):

I think you work under the impression that the second `String` parameter does not take back-references.

It does.

For instance:

```
System.out.println("foo123".replaceAll("foo(.+)", "baz$1"));
```

Output:

```
baz123
```

Answer (score 1):

It *does* accept regex as the replacement, but it uses the "dollar" notation (rather than the "backslash" notation) for back references.

So your example should have been:

```
String strNew = str.replaceAll("(.*?)\\:(.*?)&(.*?)@(.*?)","$4_$3^$2($1$2$2$1)");
```

Notice that captured group 1 is referred to as `$1`, not `\1`, etc.